# php unique identifier for clients

Tags: php, mysql, uniqueidentifier

I have a unique identifier for client i generate everytime a client request a service support.

once the id is generate, the id is inserted in the database

here my code:

```
function makeUnique() {
 $start_time = uniqid(microtime(1));
 $duration = sprintf('%0.24f', $start_time);
 return date('dmYHis').$duration;
}

echo makeUnique();
```

this output: `071120112032291320715949.928639888763427734375000`

for some reason i get 071120112032291320715949 as the number. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to remove the "." (dot) in your function. you are probably using an INT which remove numbers after the dot.

`return str_replace('.', '', date('dmYHis').$duration);`

and make sure the field is big enough - like varchar(50)

my recommendation will be to simply hash the client id using md5

`md5($clientid)`

and you have the mysql field as a char(32)

Answer (score 4):

You've already got your solution in your code. The php function uniqid() provides... well, a unique ID. If you want to ensure it's really really really really unique (though it's not necessary), just append time() to the end, like so:

```
    return uniqid().time();
```

This would also return letters mixed in with numbers (higher entropy), like this response:

```
    4eb8895a76edc1320716634
```

Comment: You can also do like this `uniqid('', TRUE)` which will add additional entropy (using the combined linear congruential generator) at the end of the return value, which increases the likelihood that the result will be unique.